# Analytics.js: What does 'auto' argument do on tracking object creation?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I've just switched to the new Google Analytics [Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en-GB) platform, using the new javascript API -  [Analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)

In the first example code snippet from [the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) a tracking object is created, then a pageview of the current page is logged using that tracking object.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Notice the `'auto'` argument - **I can't work out what that's there for**.

I had a look at the [method reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#create) and it seems that the relevant parameter is optional and should contain configuration key/value pairs. Examples can be found in the [field reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#create). If the parameter is optional it seems odd to pass `'auto'` here unless it does something of significance, so you have to assume it does, but I can't find any mention of this.

Also, in the auto generated code in your account it does a similar thing but passes your domain

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'mydomain.com');
```

The fact your domain is specifically passed when they have it available again suggests it does something meaningful - otherwise they'd probably just use `'auto'` here too. But again, there's no mention of why this is done.

Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually when I look in to code it does not pass the name of my property but the standard domain set in the configuration - which makes a lot more sense, since the parameter sets the cookie domain (in case of `"auto"` to <s>the value of `window.location.hostname`</s> to the hostname without subdomains). Alternatively you can pass a configuration object as third parameter (which might contain a cookie domain setting). Try and set a wrong parameter - you'll get a "no storage" error in the analytics debugger since the code cannot set a cookie.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Setting the cookie domain is exactly what it does. It's pretty confusing that it can be used for both that and for other configurations as well - the docs could be clearer on this. Maybe it becomes obvious why they did it that way once you start using it more?

Comment: Yeah, it's for setting the cookie and helps with tracking across sub domains. They go over in it the Google Analytics December Developer update. You can watch it here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmfUoSyFBSk

Answer (score 3):

If your concern is only with tracking across subdomains (ex: www.example.com, site1.example.com, site2.example.com), then it's already taken care of with this `auto` option in universal analytics.

[Per the 'Automatic Cookie Domain Configuration' section in this devguide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains)

> Automatic Cookie Domain Configuration simplifies cross domain tracking
>   implementations by automatically writing cookies to the highest level
>   domain possible when the auto parameter is used. When used on the
>   domain www.example.co.uk, it will try to write cookies in the
>   following order:
>
> - co.uk
> - example.co.uk
> - www.example.co.uk
>
> Analytics.js will fail to write
>   a cookie on co.uk but will succeed on example.co.uk. Since a cookie
>   was succesfully written on a higher level domain, www.example.co.uk
>   will be skipped.