# Redirect of my web page what about tracking code in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have put the tracking code of Google analytics in my website example.com

So the tracking code was `ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx', 'example.com');`

After that I redirect my website as home.com

So I have to change my tracking code as `ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx', 'home.com');`

My Google analytics account refers as  `ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx', 'auto');`

what should i put?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Analytics.js: What does 'auto' argument do on tracking object creation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066477/analytics-js-what-does-auto-argument-do-on-tracking-object-creation)

Comment: So should I put ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx', 'auto'); will it work or not?

Comment: "Auto" will set the cookie domain to the current domain where the code is placed, so that is a safe option.